# Автоматическая подстановка значения в поле таблицы SQL

Tags: sql-server

Есть две таблицы - основная и таблица-справочник с предопределенными значениями для основной, поле Type. На скриншоте подробнее.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос:
Как обеспечить автоматическую подстановку предопределенных значений из таблицы-справочника в основную при создании записи?

Comment: Если мой ответ Вас удовлетворил, то пометьте его, пожалуйста, как принятый нажатием на `v` под счетчиком голосов. Если нет, то сообщите в комментариях, какие проблемы ещё не решены

Answer (score 0):

Используйте CTE блок:

```
WITH Insert_Values_CTE ([Designation], [Number], [Type])
AS (
    SELECT ?,?,?
)
INSERT INTO dbo.Spaces
    ([Designation], [Number], [Type])
SELECT t1.[Designation], t1.[Number], t2.[Type]
FROM Insert_Values_CTE as t1
JOIN dbo.SpaceTypes as t2
ON t2.[Type] = t1.[Type]
```

В случае, если такого типа, как вставляемый, еще нет, эта команда вернет 0 вставленных строк. Тогда делаете команду вставки нового типа:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.SpaceTypes ([Type]) VALUES (?)
```

И повторяете первую команду.

`?` в командах обозначают параметрические запросы. То есть к самой команде присоединяются данные в виде отдельного параметра.